# Secure creation of new applications in Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth

How can I add IsAdminUser permissions to /o/applications/* views in Django OAuth Toolkit?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    )
}
```

in my settings.py doesn't work with Django OAuth Toolkit views, also I modify ApplicationList in my view.py doesn't work:

```
class ApplicationList:
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

I'm kind of newby to Django and Python so I will be glad for your help

Comment: instead of combining all the views you can have seperate adminvies and urls and use decorators to restrict the access

Comment: but how can I add decorator to views from Django OAuth Toolkit? Can you write step-by-step instruction?